# C++ Passing vectors to an overloaded class - some call statements work, some do not.

Tags: c++, function, class, vector

I have spent a great deal of time in google trying to figure out how to pass a vector when using .h and .cpp files between a call in main and a function in an includes block.  I was successful using class definitions.

Now everything is going fine until I want to create an overloaded function.  (I could have done this with two different classes, but I must use one overloaded function in my program.)

Here is my writeData.h file:

```
#ifndef WRITEDATA_H
#define WRITEDATA_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class writeData
{
public: writeData();
public: writeData(vector<int> & DATAFILE);
public: writeData(vector<int> & DATAFILE, string); 
};
#endif
```

The placement of the using namespace std; is another topic.

Here is my writeData.cpp file:

```
#include "writeData.h"

writeData::writeData()
{
    std::cout << "Default writeData" << std::endl;
}

writeData::writeData(vector<int> & DATAFILE)
{
    cout << "writeData 1" << endl;

    for (int var : DATAFILE)
    {
        cout << var <<endl;
    }
}

writeData::writeData(vector<int> & DATAFILE, string fileName)
{
    ofstream myfile(fileName);
    cout << "writeData" << endl;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {

        for (int var : DATAFILE)
        {
            cout << var << endl;
            myfile << var << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

And here is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "writeData.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string fileName = "test.txt";
    vector<int> items{ 10, 14, 22, 34 };

    writeData();//default
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // the next line is the problem code:
    //writeData(items);//writes to screen only 
    //<<When I uncomment it the compiler Tosses the following:
    // 'items': redefinition;     different basic types
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    writeData(items, fileName);//writes to screen and to file

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

The offending line is writeData(items);

Any assistance or pointers to online articles would be most appreciated.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) on "Most vexing parse"

Answer (score 2):

The immediate issue is that this declaration

```
writeData(items);
```

is the same as

```
writeData items;
```

hence the redefinition error. The deeper issue is that you have defined three *constructors* for a class, and seem to be attempting to call them without making a named instance. To succesfully call the one parameter constructor passing `items`, you'd need something like

```
writeData data_writer(items);
```

Alternatively, you may want either member functions, or non-members. The choice would depend on whether you really want to model a class, which maintains certain invariants or not. An example of members,

```
class writeData
{
public: 
  void write_data() const;
  void write_data(const vector<int> & DATAFILE) const;
  void write_data(const vector<int> & DATAFILE, string) const; 
};
```

Then

```
WriteData wd;
wd.write_data(items);
```

Example of non-members:

```
namespace writeData
{
  void write_data();
  void write_data(const vector<int> & DATAFILE);
  void write_data(const vector<int> & DATAFILE, string); 
};
```

Then

```
writeData::write_data(items);
```

Note I have made the `vector<int>` parameters `const` reference because they are not being moified in the functions.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to also add void in the cpp file as follows  void writeData::write_data() etc.  BTW using const at the end of the constructors in the class definition caused some issues so in taking them out everything works very well.  Have not had to code in C++ for a number of years and this helped refresh distant memories.